# Codeigniter Flash Data After Submitting Form?

Tags: codeigniter, flash

I have a question regarding form validation with Codeigniter and Flash Data. My form is located deep inside a URL string so I figured the best way to display error message on the page is with CI flash data. I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to actually display the error message. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Where am I going wrong? Thanks everyone.

```
   public function form_validate_cars()
   {
     $this->load->library('form_validation');  

         $this->form_validation->set_rules("value", "<b>Value</b>", "trim|required|is_numeric|xss_clean");
         $this->form_validation->set_rules("exterior_color", "<b>Exterior Color</b>", "trim|required|xss_clean");
         $this->form_validation->set_rules("interior_color", "<b>Interior Color</b>", "trim|required|xss_clean");
         $this->form_validation->set_rules("mileage","<b>Mileage</b>","trim|required|is_numeric|xss_clean");

         if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
          {   
             // if person does not fill in correct info, they get resubmitted back to the form.
             // redirect('site/item/2332');
             // echo 'Hello World!';
             $msg = "Please fill out proper data";
             $this->session->set_flashdata('test', $msg);
             // echo 'Please fill out needed ifnormation!';
          } 
          else 
          {

            $this->load->model('model_data');
            $this->model_data->add_new_value();
            redirect('/site/thanks');

          }

   }
```

My View

```
   echo form_open('site/form_validate_cars');

   print_r($this->session->flashdata('test'));

   echo validation_errors();

   my form continues below .......
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right after `$this->session->set_flashdata('test', $msg);` make `redirect` to desired url.

in **view**

```
if ($this->session->flashdata('result') != ''): 
    echo $this->session->flashdata('result'); 
endif;
```

better way without session

```
public function form_validate_cars()
   {
     $this->load->library('form_validation');  

         $this->form_validation->set_rules("value", "<b>Value</b>", "trim|required|is_numeric|xss_clean");
         $this->form_validation->set_rules("exterior_color", "<b>Exterior Color</b>", "trim|required|xss_clean");
         $this->form_validation->set_rules("interior_color", "<b>Interior Color</b>", "trim|required|xss_clean");
         $this->form_validation->set_rules("mileage","<b>Mileage</b>","trim|required|is_numeric|xss_clean");

       if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
          {   
             // if person does not fill in correct info, they get resubmitted back to the form.
             // redirect('site/item/2332');
             // echo 'Hello World!';
             $data['error'] = "Please fill out proper data";
             $this->load->view('desired_view', $data);
          } else {
            $this->load->model('model_data');
            $this->model_data->add_new_value();
            redirect('/site/thanks');

          }

   }
```

and in **view**

```
echo (isset($error)) ? $error : "";
```

Comment: but I'd rather go with `$data` variable to send error message to view, so you can also repopulate the form.

Answer (score 0):

After you assigned the flashdata, redirect back to the form with redirect(). This will then pick up the flashdata, make sure to check if it's filled though.